# Print output of function inside of unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am trying to print out the messages from an AWS lambda function triggered by a unit test. The code for both the lambda function and unit test are shown below. However, I don't see any messages being print from the lambda function, only the unit test messages. I've figured that I can print messages in the unit test via an `ITestOutputHelper`, but I can't do the same with the lambda function. So I used `Console.WriteLine` inside of the lambda function. How can I print the output from the lambda function when running my unit test?

Note: I'm using Rider as my IDE of choice

Console Output

[image]

Function Unit Test

```cs
public class FunctionTest
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

    public FunctionTest(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestHelloWorldFunctionHandler()
    {
        var request = new APIGatewayProxyRequest();
        var context = new TestLambdaContext();
        Dictionary<string, string> body = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "message", "hello world" }
        };

        var expectedResponse = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body),
            StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", MediaTypeNames.Application.Json } }
        };

        var response = await new Function().FunctionHandler(request, context);

        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Lambda Response: \n" + response.Body);
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Expected Response: \n" + expectedResponse.Body);
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Header: \n" + response.Headers.Values.ToArray()[0]);

        Assert.Equal(expectedResponse.Body, response.Body);
        Assert.Equal(expectedResponse.Headers, response.Headers);
        Assert.Equal(expectedResponse.StatusCode, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Lambda Function

```cs
public class Function
{
    public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest apigProxyEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello there");

        var body = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "message", "hello world" }
        };

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body),
            StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", MediaTypeNames.Application.Json } }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `ITestOutputHelper.WriteLine != Console.WriteLine`. You could probably search for a question about using an ILogger...

Comment: The way to go would be to inject `ILogger` to `Function` (either via ctor or as a parameter) and then implement a custom `ILogger` which uses `ITestOutputHelper` to write. A good example can be found here - https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-get-asp-net-core-logs-in-the-output-of-xunit-tests.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class (`Function`) you are using `Console.WriteLine`. This will not generate any output in the test. Instead you can use an [`ILogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which can be installed with [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/). When using an `ILogger` you can have several providers, which in turn can write to both [Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#logging-providers-2) and to test-output. The code below is based on a post from [meziantou.net](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-get-asp-net-core-logs-in-the-output-of-xunit-tests.htm). Read that post for a complete example. It creates an implementation for `ILogger` that will write to your test-output.

Your logger:

```
public class XUnitLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;
    private readonly LoggerExternalScopeProvider _scopeProvider;
    private readonly string _categoryName;

    public static ILogger CreateLogger(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper) => new XUnitLogger(testOutputHelper, new LoggerExternalScopeProvider(), "");

    public XUnitLogger(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, LoggerExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider, string categoryName)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
        _scopeProvider = scopeProvider;
        _categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(GetLogLevelString(logLevel))
            .Append(" [").Append(_categoryName).Append("] ")
            .Append(formatter(state, exception));

        if (exception != null)
        {
            sb.Append('\n').Append(exception);
        }

        // Append scopes
        _scopeProvider.ForEachScope((scope, state) =>
        {
            state.Append("\n => ");
            state.Append(scope);
        }, sb);

        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    private static string GetLogLevelString(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return logLevel switch
        {
            LogLevel.Trace => "trce",
            LogLevel.Debug => "dbug",
            LogLevel.Information => "info",
            LogLevel.Warning => "warn",
            LogLevel.Error => "fail",
            LogLevel.Critical => "crit",
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(logLevel))
        };
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return _scopeProvider.Push(state);
    }
}
```

Then you can change your function to the code below. If you are unable to inject it to ctor you can pass the logger as parameter to the function.

```
public class Function
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public Function(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest apigProxyEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        // Write with logger instead.
        logger.LogInformation($"Hello there");

        var body = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "message", "hello world" }
        };

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body),
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", MediaTypeNames.Application.Json } }
        };
    }
}
```

And then change your test.

```
public class FunctionTest
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

    public FunctionTest(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestHelloWorldFunctionHandler()
    {
        // .. other code 

        // Create your logger
        ILogger logger = XUnitLogger.CreateLogger(_testOutputHelper);
 
        // Inject logger.
        var response = await new Function(logger).FunctionHandler(request, context);

        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Lambda Response: \n" + response.Body);
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Expected Response: \n" + expectedResponse.Body);
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Header: \n" + response.Headers.Values.ToArray()[0]);

        Assert.Equal(expectedResponse.Body, response.Body);
        Assert.Equal(expectedResponse.Headers, response.Headers);
        Assert.Equal(expectedResponse.StatusCode, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```